# Borland linker error

Tags: linker, c++builder

I am recompling a project using Borland C++ Builder 6 and LMD tool 2010. The recompile process failed due to linker error. The message was:
"[Linker Fatal error] Fatal unable to open file LMDOneInstance.OBJ"

I searched the whole hard drive, but could not find any reference to LMDOneInstance.OBJ

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
David

Comment: I suspect it is this component vendor:
http://www.lmdinnovative.com/

Answer (score 1):

LMDOneInstance.Obj is an object code file generated a source file called LMDOneInstance.Cpp or a combined list of sources that make up the compiled object code. It could be an object file lying in a `lib` directory....

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Another good tactic is to look for

```
#pragma link "LMDOneInstance"
```

in your source code.

But tommieb's suggestion is also correct, look for LMDOneInstance.LIB and make sure it's path is in your library path or add the lib file to your project.

Comment: yes - not adding the lib file to the project can be a 'gotchya' even if you have the correct directories in the include path.